# Create pages in gatsby using different templates

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm new to gatsby and trying to programatically create pages using different templates, but I'm struggling with that.

This is my gatsby node file, and it's working great to create team members pages, but the problem appears when I want to create my blog posts using a new template located at same folder /templates

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/member-info.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

I tried different approachs but can't get a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most naive approach would be to call `createPage` with a different template component. More robust way, probably, is to define template name in frontmatter and use it to dynamically construct respective component's path, as such:

```
// some markdown file
---
template: member-info
---
```

```js
// gatsby-node.js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              template
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/${template}.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PavelYe!  I will give it a try as soon as I can

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to upvote / accept my answer if you see value in it. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the following error: _Cannot query field "template" on type "MarkdownRemarkFrontmatter"_
I understand I should define **template** name in frontmatter, but not sure how to do that

Comment: Yep, your thinking is correct. I'll update my answer. In case you aren't familiar with frontmatter => https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/#frontmatter-for-metadata-in-markdown-files