# Creating pages with different templates in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

Use case: I want to create a single use template for a specific page while also supporting default templates for a directory. In this case, I want to create an about page in markdown so that users may edit it and I want to apply a specific template to it.

In Jekyll, I could very simply achieve this with the following file structure:

```
|-about.md
|-projects/
|--project-1.md
|--project-2.md
|--project-3.md
|-templates/
|--about-page.html 
|--project-details.html
```

*about.md*

```
---
title: About us
layout: about-page
story: 
  title: Our story
  text: We were founded in 1986...
---
```

If I wanted to then apply a layout to a collection of pages, I would first initialize that collection in the config.yml and set the default layout like so:

```
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
    permalink: /project/:title
defaults: 
- scope: 
    type: "projects"
  values: 
    layout: "project-details"
```

I followed [this example](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/adding-markdown-pages/) and others like it, but they all seem to generate multiple pages and I'm making a single page with a single template and any attempt to add another query has resulted in errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L32Vx_bEZhA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hw1g77I35ZivVLe8k2nvjB) I followed destructured the query const and that sent me down a whole rabbit hole of trying and failing solutions meant for older versions of gatsby. The lightbulb went off when I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59334699/3411192) and all I needed to do was keep the const intact and use dots for the forEach call like I did back before I started in on ES6 and react.

*gatsby-config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    {
      //calls the plugin
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      //settings for the plugin
      options: {
        //what to call the directory
        name: `projects`,
        //where to find the directory
        path: `${__dirname}/src/projects/`,
      },
    },
    //locate the pages
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        name: "pages",
      },
    },
    //for the images in the project-details template 
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, // Needed for dynamic images,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

*gatsby-node.js*

```
const path = require('path');
exports.createPages = async ({graphql,actions }) => {
  //get all the pages, use slug as unique id
  const projects = await graphql(`
    query Projects {
      allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/(projects)/" } }) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  //loop through the pages
  projects.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    //create a page for each
    actions.createPage({
      // create the path
      path: '/projects/'+node.frontmatter.slug,
      // add the component. path.resolve allows us to use the dot notation
      component: path.resolve('./src/templates/project-details.js'),
      // defines the slug variable that is passed into the query on the template, which gets all the page content 
      context: {
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug
      }
    })
  });

  //publish pages with custom templates 
  const customPages = await graphql(`
    query templatePages {
      //get only markdown pages that have a template defined in their frontmatter
      allMarkdownRemark(filter: {frontmatter: {template: {ne: null}}}) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  //loop through the pages
  customPages.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    //create a page for each
    actions.createPage({
      // create the path based on the slug
      path: node.frontmatter.slug,
      //use the template frontmatter to get the template of the same name. 
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/${node.frontmatter.template}.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug
      }
    })
  });
}
```

*templates/about-page.js*

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
export default function AboutTemplate({data}) {
  const { markdownRemark } = data 
  const { frontmatter } = markdownRemark
  return (
    <Layout>
      <main>
        <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <section>
          <h2>{frontmatter.story.title}</h2>
          <div>{frontmatter.story.text}</div>
        </section> 
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const aboutPageQuery = graphql`
  query AboutPage($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        story {
          text
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*templates/project-details.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'
import * as styles from '../styles/project-details.module.css'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

export default function ProjectDetails({data}) {
  const { html } = data.markdownRemark;
  const { title, stack, featuredImg } = data.markdownRemark.frontmatter;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.details}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <h3>{stack}</h3>
        <div className={styles.featured}>
          <GatsbyImage image={ featuredImg.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData }/>
        </div>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} className={styles.html}/>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query Projects($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        stack
        title
        featuredImg {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Though this was the simplest solution given my knowledge, I am wondering if it is indeed the best.